# how to remove from the back of the list?? The list currently has "stir it up, pokemon theme"

Tags: c, linked-list

This is my `removeFromTheBack` function. The input list contains two strings: "Stir it up" and  "Pokemon theme". I want the function to remove from the back of the list and return the removed element. However, I can't seem to know what the problem is because it is not removing what I want it to remove. Any help?

```
MusicRec*removeFromBack(MusicRec*theList)
{
    MusicRec*temp;

    if(theList == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    temp=theList->next;
    while(temp->next->next !=NULL)
    {
        temp=theList->next;
    }

    temp->next=NULL;

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove characters or words from “stir it up, pokemon theme”?? Can you post the output you are getting now?

Comment: the list has these two elements "stir it up" and "pokemon theme. I want to remove the words. It should return pokemon theme but right now its returning stir it up

Comment: What if the list have only *one* node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
while(temp->next->next !=NULL)
{
    temp=theList->next;
}

temp->next=NULL;

return temp;
```

when the loop exits, `temp` will be pointing at last but one node and you're returning that. However, the node you want to return, the last one, is removed from the list here

```
temp->next=NULL;
```

To return the last node, do

```
while(temp->next->next !=NULL)
{
    temp=theList->next;
}
temp2=temp->next;
temp->next=NULL;

return temp2;
```

where `temp2` will be pointing to the last node. You can add one more `if` statement to handle the case where the list has only one node like this

```
if(theList->next == NULL)
{
    temp=theList;
    theList=NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: @user3380932 ok fine. read about using [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about). indicate right or usefull answers.

Answer (score -1):

From your comment on the first post

> the list has these two elements "stir it up" and "pokemon theme. I want to remove the words. It should return pokemon theme but right now its returning stir it up

it seems what you really want is to remove an element from the front. The simplest approach to doing that is this

- Find the first item in the list
- Return its next element

You could accomplish that by doing this

```
MusicRec*removeFromFront(MusicRec*theList)
{
    if(theList == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return theList->next;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: the function called `removeFromTheBack`, why do you assume he wants to remove the first element ?

Comment: To cite the questioner: """the list has these two elements "stir it up" and "pokemon theme. I want to remove the words. It should return pokemon theme but right now its returning stir it up""". It seems it is the first element that should be removed. Why do you assume the OP is a "he"?